# Is something wrong in SQL query?

Tags: sql, oracle

In toad i am trying to extract the data but when i put between condition the data output coming is wrong....
Please let me know if i am missing something....please help...

```
SELECT B.USER_NAME AS CREATED_BY
    ,A.CREATION_DATE
    ,C.USER_NAME
    ,A.LAST_UPDATE_DATE
    ,A.PFIZER_ITEMCODE
    ,A.SYSTEM_ITEMCODE AS ORACLE_ITEM_CODE
    ,A.ITEM_DESCRIPTION
    ,A.BATCH_NUMBER
    ,A.MFR_CODE
    ,A.MFR_DESC AS MFR_DESCRIPTION
    ,TO_CHAR(A.MFR_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY') AS MFR_DATE
    ,TO_CHAR(A.EXPIRY_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY') AS EXPIRY_DATE
    ,TO_CHAR(A.EFFECTIVE_FROM, 'DD-MON-YYYY') AS EFFECTIVE_FROM
    ,A.EFFECTIVE_TO
    ,A.EXCISE AS EXCISE_AMOUNT
    ,A.EXCISE_RATE
    ,A.P2S
    ,A.P2R
    ,A.MRP
    ,A.STATE_CODE
    ,A.STATE
    ,(CASE SUBSTR(A.SYSTEM_ITEMCODE, 6, 2)
            WHEN ('PI')
                THEN 'OIP'
            WHEN ('PF')
                THEN 'OPF'
            ELSE 'OWL'
            END
        ) AS LEGAL_ENTITY
FROM xxdhl_pf_batch_pricing A
    ,fnd_user B
    ,fnd_user c
WHERE 1 = 1
    AND A.CREATED_BY = B.USER_ID
    AND A.LAST_UPDATED_BY = C.USER_ID
    AND TO_CHAR(A.CREATION_DATE, 'DD-Mon-YYYY') BETWEEN '01-Jan-2015'
        AND '08-Jan-2015'
```

Comment: If you want anyone to spend time, tag correctly - are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle? And, please, format the select-list. And describe what's wrong with the result you get!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the right coding for the above query is

```
'AND TRUNC(A.CREATION_DATE) BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-JAN-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AND TO_DATE('08-JAN-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY')`
```

as suggested by [BobJarvis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/213136/bob-jarvis)

Really very helpful answer...thanks all

Answer (score 5):

You should fix the join syntax and formatting.  Simple rule:  Never use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use explicit `JOIN` syntax.

But your problem is probably the date.  Do date comparisons as *dates* not as *strings*:

```
TRUNC(A.CREATION_DATE) BETWEEN DATE '2015-01-01' and DATE '2015-01-08'
```

The `DATE` keyword is very handy, because then you can put the date constants in the ISO standard YYYY-MM-DD format.

Comment: @gordon...i understand but is there any way to get the data through DD-MON-YYYY format because the value where user is puting is in that format...

Comment: @KalpeshKoli: use `TO_DATE(date_string, 'DD-MON-YYYY')`.

Comment: You need to change the entire portion of the WHERE clause relating to the date so you're working with DATE values everywhere. Change the last line of the WHERE clause to 'AND TRUNC(A.CREATION_DATE) BETWEEN TO_DATE('01-JAN-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY') AND TO_DATE('08-JAN-2015', 'DD-MON-YYYY')`. Best of luck.